# HG clone only log files

Tags: mercurial, repository, clone, tortoisehg

How to clone only log files of Mercurial repo like this:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket... --partial
```

To make queryes to get information about files,branches or smth else like this:

```
hg files
```

Comment: You can check https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hg-experimental/src/69ccc796d4bab8a4dfa94784043991c11163f2ea/remotefilelog/?at=default, but it will likely require a support on the server-side.
What is your ultimate goal? Getting some stats from a big repository without having to clone it entirely?

Comment: @lothiraldan yes, getting stats without clonning all files from big repositories

Comment: Did you try the extension?